# JBoss 7.2.0 Set poolMaxSize on MDB error

Tags: jboss7.x, ejb-3.0

When I try to set the poolMaxSize attribute on my Message Driven Bean, I encounter this issue

"JBAS014746: pool-max-size may not be null"

I see the same response both when I try to set it via jconsole as well as via mBeanServerConnection.setAttribute code.

Can anyone please guide me on how to set the value for this attribute?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are talking about "maxSession" property, which specifies the maximum amount of mdb instances that can process messages.. If that is the case, then you should use maxSession property

```
@MessageDriven(name = "MessageMDBSample", activationConfig = {
     @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
     @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "queue/sampleQueue"),
     @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxSession", propertyValue = "10"),
     @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge") })
```

In the previous example, it was set to 10 instances